# Assigning ngModel to month control

Tags: angular, angular5

I want to bind through ngModel a date object which has current month value display the month and year on the input month calendar. The problem is the object gets bind to the control but does not display the month/year. Any pointers would be helpful.

Here's the sample code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8y1nap

I want the current month/year to be displayed by default when the page loads.

Comment: The code you have provided is just a skeleton angular project, there's no control or calendar or anything.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, we can create a custom Date pipe and install moment js:

```
import {Pipe, ChangeDetectorRef, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';
const momentConstructor: (value?: any) => moment.Moment = (<any>moment).default || moment;
 @Pipe({ name: 'amDateFormat' })
export class DateFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(value: Date | moment.Moment | string | number, ...args: any[]): 
string {
   if (!value) return '';
  return momentConstructor(value).format(args[0]);
  }
}
```